# Line Curve Set end to raycast hit?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Hi like in topic how to set line curve end to raycast Hit position in geometry nodes ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a curve, you can select the start and end point with the node `Endpoint Selection` and pass it as selection to the node `Set Position`.

This way you apply the new position to only one of the two endpoints.

[image]

Comment: Not working on my example I've added image abowe. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share your blend file? it's hard to see what exactly you mean. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I've managed it after instances on points I forgot to realize instances... so Question is resolved. Thanks